# full height header picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am looking at this site here:
[platetheslate](http://www.platetheslate.com/)

I found it from another users question on here but I have one of my own.

How do they make the header image `FULL HEIGHT`? I know you can get a full width/height with even CSS "cover" element but thats not what I am getting at.

How did they set it, so no matter what size your display/window it takes up the full screen (height wise), no matter what you always just see the photo UNTIL you scroll down.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should scale the width in proportion with the height.

```
#id {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the header's css class, do `height: 100%`

Answer (score 1):

Note their Javascript is unminified here: http://www.platetheslate.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/jquery.main.js

Here is the method that sets the height and width of the image:

```
//initHImage
function initHImage() {
    var minWidth = 1100;
    var holder = jQuery('#h-image');
    var image = holder.find('img');
    var win = jQuery(window);
    var ratio = image.width() / image.height()

    image.removeAttr('height width');
    holder.css({
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'relative'
    });

    function setSize() {
        var winW = win.width();
        var winH = win.height();
        var W = Math.max(winW, minWidth);
        var winRatio = W / winH;

        holder.css({
            width: W,
            height: winH
        });

        if(winRatio > ratio) {
            image.css({
                width: W,
                height: W / ratio,
                marginTop: Math.min((W - W / ratio) / 2, 0),
                marginLeft: 0
            });
        }
        else {
            image.css({
                width: winH * ratio,
                height: winH,
                marginTop:0,
                marginLeft: Math.min((W - winH * ratio) / 2, 0)
            });
        }
    }
    setSize();

    win.bind('resize orientationchange', setSize);
}
```

Comment: The best when you need to find out *that* site does a full size image.